# Alternatives to EngineYard for automated Rails hosting in Singapore region?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, engineyard

EngineYard charges $50/server in their standard support plan (not optional). In a small cluster of 5 instances, you end up paying more for support than the hardware cost. Per incident support pricing is also not available.
Heroku does not provides instances in Singapore region - hence it's not an option.

We are a small dev team and cannot afford to invest in a techops guy right now (hence Linode is also out).

Any other alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are now exploring AWS OpsWorks. Its very similar - just with no safety net :)